# Inject a set of named arguments in an R function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I call the same function, with the same (except of one) list of parameters:

```
library(ggpubr)

df %>% ggline(x = "month", y = "avg_salary", color = 'approach', add = 'mean')
df %>% ggline(x = "day",   y = "avg_salary", color = 'approach', add = 'mean')
df %>% ggline(x = "week",  y = "avg_salary", color = 'approach', add = 'mean')
```

Is there a way to do it like that:

```
params <- list(y = "avg_salary", color = 'approach', add = 'mean')

df %>% ggline(x = "month", !!!params )
df %>% ggline(x = "day", !!!params)
df %>% ggline(x = "week", !!!params)
```

Apparently `!!!` doesn't work. What is the right way to inject a set of named arguments here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `inject()` to explicitly enable `!!!`.

```r
rlang::inject(df %>% ggline(x = "week", !!!params))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also pretty straightforward using `do.call` in base R:

```r
library(ggpubr)

params <- list(data = mtcars, x = 'wt', y = 'mpg', color = 'cyl',
               numeric.x.axis = TRUE)

do.call(ggline, params)
```

[image]